# How to extract value of attribute in a nested tag structure using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have a html file which looks something similar to this :

```
<html>
...
<li class="not a user"> </li>
<li class="user">
 <a href="abs" ...> </a>
</li>
<li class="user">
 <a href="bss" ...> </a>
</li>
...
</html>
```

given the above input I want to parse the li tags with class="user" and get the value of the href's as output. is this possible using beautifulsoup in python ???

my solution was:

```
data="the above html code snippet"
soup=BeautifulSoup(data)
listset=soup("li","user")
for list in listset:
   attrib_value=[a['href'] for a in list.findAll('a',{'href':True})]
```

obviously i have an error somewhere that it only lists the attribute value for the last anchor tag's href.

Comment: why are you setting the attrib_value over and over again on each loop? what are you doing with it on each iteration?

Comment: the problem is i just kept reassigning on each iteration when I wanted a list of attribute values ! :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine. There are three elements in `listset` - and `attrib_value` gets overridden in each iteration of your loop, so at the end of the program, it only contains the href values from the last element of `listset`, which is `bss`.

Try this instead to keep all values:

```
attrib_value += [a['href'] for a in list.findAll('a',{'href':True})]
```

and initialize attrib_value to the empty list before the loop (`attrib_value = []`).